# Como ativar um onChange que utiliza options de um select via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho o seguinte select com o onChange gerarImagem funcionando corretamente:

```
<select id="tipo" name="tipo" onchange="gerarImagem(this.options[this.selectedIndex])">
        <option value=""></option>
        <c:forEach items="${FORM.listaTipos}" var="t">
                <option value="${t.codTipo}" id="${t.qtdMaxReg}">${t.descTipo}</option>                 
        </c:forEach>
</select>
```

E o seguinte init para a página,não estou sabendo o que passar como parâmetro no na chamada gerarImagem para que possa manipular essas opções via JavaScript.

```
function init() {
     if(document.getElementById('tipo').value != null){
            gerarImagem(document.getElementById('tipo').options[document.getElementById('tipo').value]); //ESTOU PASSANDO O PARÂMETRO OPCOES ERRADO AQUI, O QUE PODE SER FEITO?
    }
}
```

Tenho essa função gerarImagem, porém não estou conseguindo manipula-la via javascript ja que a mesma utiliza um parâmetro options. A função funciona corretamente caso a opção seja ativada manualmente, porém chamando no init não.

```
function gerarImagem(opcoes) {
        var spanImagem = document.getElementById('spanImagem');
        var maxReg = opcoes.id; //ERRO
        dwr.util.byId("tdUpload").style.visibility = 'visible';
        dwr.util.byId("tdUploadTxt").style.visibility = 'hidden';


    switch(opcoes.value) ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
gerarImagem(document   
   .getElementById('tipo')
   .options[document.getElementById('tipo')
   .selectedIndex]
);
```

Comment: ?? Essa linha não ta errada, eu recebo erro nela pois não consegui passar o options logo não consegue encontrar opcoes.id

Comment: no trecho options[document.getElementById('tipo').value] tenta trocar o value por selectedIndex

Comment: funcionou, obrigado, edita a resposta principal que aceito a resposta