# Não se pode usar onclick em uma option de um select?

Tags: javascript, html5, html-select

Tenho um script que ao clicar em uma option especifica chamaria uma função no javascript com onclick, mas esse script só esta funcionando no firefox desktop nos demais navegadores não funciona, venho desconfiando que o problema etá sendo causado por estar usando onclick nas options, existe alguma forma alternativa de eu conseguir o desejado sem utilizar o onclick?, realmente não se deve usar o onclick em uma option de select?

Meu select:

```
<select class="custom-select" name="tamanho" id="tamanho" required="required">
        <option selected value="Nenhum">Escolha...</option>
        <option value="G" onclick="mostraG()">Grande (G)</option>
        <option value="M" onclick="mostraM()">Média (M)</option>
      </select>
```

Meu JS:

```
// Mostra M e oculta G
function mostraM(){
    if (document.getElementById('pizzaM').style.display == "none"){
        document.getElementById('pizzaM').style.display = "block",
    document.getElementById('pizzaG').style.display = "none",
    $("#sabor1G").val("Nenhum"),
    $("#sabor2G").val("Nenhum"),
    console.log("WORK");
    }
}
// Mostra G e culta M
function mostraG(){
    if (document.getElementById('pizzaG').style.display == "none"){
        document.getElementById('pizzaG').style.display = "block",
    document.getElementById('pizzaM').style.display = "none",
    $("#sabor1M").val("Nenhum"),
    $("#sabor2M").val("Nenhum"),
    console.log("WORK");
    }
}
```

Comment: Já tentou com `$('#tamanho').on.('change', function(){})`

Comment: Poderia me mostrar um exemplo?

Comment: Sim. Um momento

Comment: O que realmente precisa que seja realizado no seu select? Se deseja executar uma função quando cada opção é selecionada a melhor opção é onchange no select.  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/365402/gostaria-de-saber-como-receber-o-valor-do-meu-select-ao-clicar-em-um-option-com/365408#365408

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/238457/como-ativar-um-onchange-que-utiliza-options-de-um-select-via-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voce pode fazer assim:

```js
$('#tamanho').on('change', function () {
  let value = $(this).val()

  if (value == 'G') {
    mostraG()
  } else {
    mostraM()
  }
});

function mostraM() {
  console.log("mostraM");
}

function mostraG() {
  console.log("mostraG");
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<select class="custom-select" name="tamanho" id="tamanho" required="required">
        <option selected value="Nenhum">Escolha...</option>
        <option value="G" >Grande (G)</option>
        <option value="M" >Média (M)</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o  `$('#tamanho').on('change', function(){` para escolher a opções

Olhe o exemplo

```js
$('#tamanho').on('change', function(){
  const value = $(this).val()
  if( value == 'Nenhum' ){
     nenhum()
  }
  else{
    if( value == 'G' ){
       mostraG()
    }else{
      mostraM()
    }
  }
})


const mostraM = () =>{
   $('.pizzaM').fadeIn()
   $('.pizzaG').fadeOut()
}

const mostraG = () =>{
   $('.pizzaM').fadeOut()
   $('.pizzaG').fadeIn()
}

const nenhum = () =>{
   $('.pizzaM').fadeOut()
   $('.pizzaG').fadeOut()
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select class="custom-select" name="tamanho" id="tamanho" required="required">
        <option selected value="Nenhum">Escolha...</option>
        <option value="G" >Grande (G)</option>
        <option value="M" >Média (M)</option>
</select>

<div class="pizzaM" style="display:none">
  Pizza M
</div>

<div class="pizzaG" style="display:none">
  Pizza G
</div>
```

Espero que ajude